# How to return to the decryption request

Tags: boot, command-line, 18.04, encryption, reboot

I encrypted the hard disk with LUKS.

When I boot the PC, the screen says: please unlock disk sda5_crypt.

Is it possible to return to this screen from the command-line? If the PC can return from the unlocked state, it is OK even if not from the command-line. Is restarting my PC the only way to fix this problem?

I executed the command `$ lsblk -a` and I paste the output.

```
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                    7:0    0  88.5M  1 loop  /snap/core/7270
loop1                    7:1    0 160.2M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
loop2                    7:2    0  54.7M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1650
loop3                    7:3    0  89.1M  1 loop  /snap/core/8268
loop4                    7:4    0  44.9M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
loop5                    7:5    0   4.2M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-calculator/544
loop6                    7:6    0  54.7M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1668
loop7                    7:7    0  14.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-characters/399
loop8                    7:8    0  42.8M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
loop9                    7:9    0  14.8M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-characters/375
loop10                   7:10   0   3.7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-system-monitor/123
loop11                   7:11   0   3.7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
loop12                   7:12   0     4M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-calculator/406
loop13                   7:13   0   956K  1 loop  /snap/gnome-logs/81
loop14                   7:14   0  1008K  1 loop  /snap/gnome-logs/61
loop15                   7:15   0 156.7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
loop16                   7:16   0         0 loop  
sda                      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                   8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                   8:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                   8:3    0 464.6G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt         253:0    0 464.6G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root  253:1    0 463.6G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1
                       253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

### Screenshots of Disks with detailed info for each partition

- [/dev/sda1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGvSk.png)
  [image: /dev/sda1]
- [/dev/sda2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuCbK.png)
- [/dev/sda3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bedIQ.png)
- [/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCe56.png)
- [unallocated space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4xwk.png)
- [/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg/root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ghnr.png)
- [/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg/swap_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDGZj.png)

Add
 
Thank you for answering!
 
I tried the command, but I got the following error.
 
`Failed to hibernate system via logind: Sleep verb not supported`
 
I did a search and it said that disabling secure boot is the solution.
 
Althought I tried, it didn't work.
 
At first, I seem to have to solve the problem of hibernating ubuntu 18.04...

Comment: I don't see any `sda5_crypt`. I only see `sda3_crypt`. Is there a `sda5_crypt` that does not show up in the `lsblk -a` output? If so, can you open the app "Disks" and select the `sda5_crypt` in there and take a screenshot? Add the screenshot in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that I know of is to hibernate the system. Try the following command:

```
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

Personally I have one PC that this fails to work on (system restarts as if shut down) and another where this works.

**If** your system can successfully hibernate, then you'll arrive at the password prompt when you turn it back on, and then the system will start where you left off.